# How do i create a margin of error of 10% on python using 2 different sized strings

Tags: python, sequence, percentage

I have 2 strings.
The first string is a primer which contains "ATTACATGGTTTACAACTTT"
The second string contains my reverse sequence in a dictionary which is:
}"GGCGGAGCGCATTAAGGCCTATAGTTACTCGAGGGGCCAGGTGTAATATGTTGGGGTAGGCGGTAAAACTTGTAGACGTGAGCGTTTGCTGCATGTTAATGTTAAGGGTTCCGTGGAGAAAAGTGTAAGAAAGTGTGGTTACGAGGCTAGGTGTCAGCGGCAGTATCATAGGCCGTTGAAGTAGAAGCAATCGACGTTTTTCGGTAGAGGCAACGTTGAGTTACCGCAGAAGGAGTGTGTGGGTCAACGGGGGAGAGAGTTCAGGGTGAGGACGACCAAGAACCCTAGCTTGGGAGGTTATGTCAATGTATAGCCACTTCATAAATTCAGTGTTATTCGCAATCCGGGTGTCGAGACCATGGGTAGCGTGAGCAGGCAACCATTTGAGGTCTTGGCCGAGGTAGGGGTACTACTGCCCTAGGTGCATACAGCGAGTTCTGAGGGACGCCGTGAATTACAGTTAGAGCTCATCTACGACATCAACCAGTGGTACTTGCACATACGGTGGAGGAGAGACAAGAGGCATTTCAACATTTGGTACATTAGATCAAGAGCGTGGAGGCCATA" :"n\GGCGGAGCGCATTAAGGCCTATAGTTACTCGAGGGGCCAGGTGTAATATGTTGGGGTAGGCGGTAAAACTTGTAGACGTGAGCGTTTGCTGCATGTTAATGTTAAGGGTTCCGTGGAGAAAAGTGTAAGAAAGTGTGGTTACGAGGCTAGGTGTCAGCGGCAGTATCATAGGCCGTTGAAGTAGAAGCAATCGACGTTTTTCGGTAGAGGCAACGTTGAGTTACCGCAGAAGGAGTGTGTGGGTCAACGGGGGAGAGAGTTCAGGGTGAGGACGACCAAGAACCCTAGCTTGGGAGGTTATGTCAATGTATAGCCACTTCATAAATTCAGTGTTATTCGCAATCCGGGTGTCGAGACCATGGGTAGCGTGAGCAGGCAACCATTTGAGGTCTTGGCCGAGGTAGGGGTACTACTGCCCTAGGTGCATACAGCGAGTTCTGAGGGACGCCGTGAATTACAGTTAGAGCTCATCTACGACATCAACCAGTGGTACTTGCACATACGGTGGAGGAGAGACAAGAGGCATTTCAACATTTGGTACATTAGATCAAGAGCGTGGAGGCCATA" ,"TGGCGGTCGCATTAAGGCGTATAGTTAATCGAGAGGCCAGGTTTAGTGTGTTGGGGTAGGCGGTAAAACTTGTAGGCGTAACCGTTTGCTGCATGTTAATGTTAGCAATTCCGTGGAGAGAAGTGTAAGAAAGTTTGGTTACGGGGCTAGGTGTCAGCGGTGATATCATAGGCCGTTGAAGTACAAGAAATCGAAGTTTTTGGGTAGTAGAGGACACGTTGAGTTGCCGCAGGAGGAGTGTGTGGGTCAGGGGGGGAGAGAGTTCAGGGTAAGGACAACCAAGAACCCTAGCTTGGGAGGTTATGTCAATGTTTGGCCACTGCACAAATCTAGTGTCATTCGCATTCCGGGTGTCGAGAATTTTGATAGCGTGAGCAGTCAACCATTTCTGGTCATGGCCGAGGTAGGGCAACTACCGCACTAGGTGCACTTAGACAGTTTTGAGGGACGCCGTGAGTGACAGTTAGAGCTCATCTACGACACCAAACAGTAGTCCTTGCACAGTCACTGGAGGAGAGACAAAAGACACTTTAACATTGAGTACATTAAATTAACAGCGTGGAGACCATACGGTGATTTGACCTAAGGTAGGGTGCCTGGTGAGGCAACGTCAGCTTTTAGTGAAAGGGATTTGGTTTTGAGTCCGTTAGGGGAAACTCACAGCTCAAACATTCATTTTAAGGGCGAACTGCCTAGTAGTTTTGAAGAGGTACTAGATTCCTTAGATAACTGGGGACAAAACTCTAGCATTGGGTCAAAGTAGAGGCCTTCATTTCATAGTCATCCTTTTAGCTTTGAAACGGTGTTCTTAGGTGAACCCAGCAACAACAACCACATAGAGTCATGTTTTAAAGGCAATCGCTCTTCGAGACGGTGATGGCCTCTAAAATGTAAAGGACATCATTCTAAGCAGCTGGTCTGTCCAAATAGTCTCACTAGCTCCTACTGTTCCAATGGCA" :"n\TGGCGGTCGCATTAAGGCGTATAGTTAATCGAGAGGCCAGGTTTAGTGTGTTGGGGTAGGCGGTAAAACTTGTAGGCGTAACCGTTTGCTGCATGTTAATGTTAGCAATTCCGTGGAGAGAAGTGTAAGAAAGTTTGGTTACGGGGCTAGGTGTCAGCGGTGATATCATAGGCCGTTGAAGTACAAGAAATCGAAGTTTTTGGGTAGTAGAGGACACGTTGAGTTGCCGCAGGAGGAGTGTGTGGGTCAGGGGGGGAGAGAGTTCAGGGTAAGGACAACCAAGAACCCTAGCTTGGGAGGTTATGTCAATGTTTGGCCACTGCACAAATCTAGTGTCATTCGCATTCCGGGTGTCGAGAATTTTGATAGCGTGAGCAGTCAACCATTTCTGGTCATGGCCGAGGTAGGGCAACTACCGCACTAGGTGCACTTAGACAGTTTTGAGGGACGCCGTGAGTGACAGTTAGAGCTCATCTACGACACCAAACAGTAGTCCTTGCACAGTCACTGGAGGAGAGACAAAAGACACTTTAACATTGAGTACATTAAATTAACAGCGTGGAGACCATACGGTGATTTGACCTAAGGTAGGGTGCCTGGTGAGGCAACGTCAGCTTTTAGTGAAAGGGATTTGGTTTTGAGTCCGTTAGGGGAAACTCACAGCTCAAACATTCATTTTAAGGGCGAACTGCCTAGTAGTTTTGAAGAGGTACTAGATTCCTTAGATAACTGGGGACAAAACTCTAGCATTGGGTCAAAGTAGAGGCCTTCATTTCATAGTCATCCTTTTAGCTTTGAAACGGTGTTCTTAGGTGAACCCAGCAACAACAACCACATAGAGTCATGTTTTAAAGGCAATCGCTCTTCGAGACGGTGATGGCCTCTAAAATGTAAAGGACATCATTCTAAGCAGCTGGTCTGTCCAAATAGTCTCACTAGCTCCTACTGTTCCAATGGCA" ,"TAGACTGTATTTCTAGAACTGGTGGCGGTTACATTAAGGCGTATAGTTGCTCGAGAGGCCAGGTTTAGTGTGTTGGGGTAGACGGTAAAACTTGTAGGCGTAAGCGTTTTCTGCATGTTAATGTTAGTAATTCCGTGGAGAGGAGTGTAAGAAAGCCTGGTTACGAGGCTAAGTGTCAGCGGAGATATCATAGGCCGTTGAAGTACAAGAAATCGAAGTTTTTGGGTAGAGGACACGTTGAATTGCCGCAGAAGGAGTGTGTGGGTCAAGGGGGGAGAGAGTTCAGGGTGAGGACAACCAAGAACCCAAATTTGGGAGGTTGTGTCAATGTTTGGCCACTGCACGAATCCAGTGTTATTCGCATCCCGGGTGTCGAGAACATGTGTAGCGTGAGCAGTCGACCATTTCTGGTCTTGGCCAAGGTAAGGCAACTACCGCCCTAGGTGCACTTAGCCAGTTTTGAGGGACTCCGTCAGTGACAGTTAGAGCTCATCTACGACACCAACCAGTAGTCCTTGCACATTCGCTGGAGGAGAGACAAGAGACACTTTAACATTCAGTACATTAAATTAACAGCGTGGAGCCCATACGGTGATTAGACCTAAGGTAAGGTGCCTGGTGAGGCAACGTCAGCTTTTAGTGAAAGGGATTTGGTTTTGAGTCCGTTGGGGGAAGCTCACAGCTAAAACATTCATTTTAAGGGCGAACTGCCTAGTAGACCTGAAGAGGTACTAGATTCCTTATACAACTCGGCACAAAACTTTAACATTGGATCAAAGTAGAGACCTTCATCTCATAGTCATCCTTTTAGCTTTGAAACGGTGTTCTTAGGTGAACCCAGCAACGACAACCACATAGATTCATGTTTTAAAGGCAAACGGTCTTCGAGACGGTGGTGGCCTCTAAAGTGTAAAGGACATCATACCAAGCAGCTGGTCTGTCCAAATGGTCTCAGTAGCTCCTCCTGCTCTAAGCGCACCCTCTGAGACTCCCAAGGGTATCTCAATCTTTCTCCCAACAGAGATAAACGTTGGGTACGCATTCAAGAGAGTCCCTGAAAGAATATGGTATAAGGCTCCATGGTTTCTCTAAACCTAGGTC" :"n\TAGACTGTATTTCTAGAACTGGTGGCGGTTACATTAAGGCGTATAGTTGCTCGAGAGGCCAGGTTTAGTGTGTTGGGGTAGACGGTAAAACTTGTAGGCGTAAGCGTTTTCTGCATGTTAATGTTAGTAATTCCGTGGAGAGGAGTGTAAGAAAGCCTGGTTACGAGGCTAAGTGTCAGCGGAGATATCATAGGCCGTTGAAGTACAAGAAATCGAAGTTTTTGGGTAGAGGACACGTTGAATTGCCGCAGAAGGAGTGTGTGGGTCAAGGGGGGAGAGAGTTCAGGGTGAGGACAACCAAGAACCCAAATTTGGGAGGTTGTGTCAATGTTTGGCCACTGCACGAATCCAGTGTTATTCGCATCCCGGGTGTCGAGAACATGTGTAGCGTGAGCAGTCGACCATTTCTGGTCTTGGCCAAGGTAAGGCAACTACCGCCCTAGGTGCACTTAGCCAGTTTTGAGGGACTCCGTCAGTGACAGTTAGAGCTCATCTACGACACCAACCAGTAGTCCTTGCACATTCGCTGGAGGAGAGACAAGAGACACTTTAACATTCAGTACATTAAATTAACAGCGTGGAGCCCATACGGTGATTAGACCTAAGGTAAGGTGCCTGGTGAGGCAACGTCAGCTTTTAGTGAAAGGGATTTGGTTTTGAGTCCGTTGGGGGAAGCTCACAGCTAAAACATTCATTTTAAGGGCGAACTGCCTAGTAGACCTGAAGAGGTACTAGATTCCTTATACAACTCGGCACAAAACTTTAACATTGGATCAAAGTAGAGACCTTCATCTCATAGTCATCCTTTTAGCTTTGAAACGGTGTTCTTAGGTGAACCCAGCAACGACAACCACATAGATTCATGTTTTAAAGGCAAACGGTCTTCGAGACGGTGGTGGCCTCTAAAGTGTAAAGGACATCATACCAAGCAGCTGGTCTGTCCAAATGGTCTCAGTAGCTCCTCCTGCTCTAAGCGCACCCTCTGAGACTCCCAAGGGTATCTCAATCTTTCTCCCAACAGAGATAAACGTTGGGTACGCATTCAAGAGAGTCCCTGAAAGAATATGGTATAAGGCTCCATGGTTTCTCTAAACCTAGGTC"{

I want to run my primer though this sequence and add up to a 10% margin of error. What code can be used to do this.
Thanks for any help it would mean a lot :)

Comment: What is "error"? What is "run primer through a sequence"? What is that dictionary supposed to contain?

Comment: soooo, you want to compare the strings and see how similar they are?

Comment: Margin of error allows me to have up to a certain pecentage of error for example my primer is 20 chracaters long so that means as long as its 18 charcaters it will be fine.

Comment: The primer is within its own dictionary and and sequence is in its own

Comment: Yes but running the primer through the sequence and allow up to 18 charcters in the primer to be present in 20 charcaters

Comment: The matching string can be found at any position (from first to 20th but also say from 3rd to 22nd), or do you want to check by blocks (the first 20 chars, them 21th to 40th, ...)? And the matching values must be consecutive, or a string with say 10 correct values, 2 wrong, and then 8 correct again would still be a match?

Comment: And btw, why do you keep a dictionary where for each `key:value` pair `key` and `value` are identical?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.